# What is with the Electorate badge, why does it have a different vote count than Civic Duty?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

When I look at my progress under the review tab, I see the following numbers (will include a picture if requested)

Progress (Graphic Bar) Badge Name

- 788 ------ 300 Civic Duty
- 321 ------ 600 Electorate

Where did the other 457 votes go towards earning the Electorate Badge? Shouldn't both badges show the same progress, or was their some point (the new review process) that restarted the count?

(Note: Reviewer and Copy Editor also differ in count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Electorate](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/badges/28/electorate) only measures question votes whereas [Civic Duty](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/badges/18/civic-duty) measures votes on all posts.

You can consult this excellent [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) for all the gory details on badges.  There are several reasons why the totals between Reviewer and Copy Editor could (and probably will) differ.

Comment: Doh. There goes my reading comprehension.